# "Template Rendering is not supported in texture atlases" SpriteKit and Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, sprite-kit, sktextureatlas

I am making a game in SpriteKit and I am using a texture atlas for all of my textures. I am using the setting

- Scale Factors: Single Vector

Xcode is giving me a warning for this TextureAtlas :

> Template rendering is not supported in texture atlases.

I am unsure what this means

Comment: show the code please

Comment: Well the only time I use code that uses an SKTextureAtlas is: let gameTextures = SKTextureAtlas("Textures")

Comment: Simone is correct show the code and the settings being applied inside of your question

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted, this is a valid question, and there is no code pertaining to the problem.

Comment: Yeah I know, the problem isn't the code, it is the xassets folder setup I have and even then I have posted the only setting of which I have changed from my default image set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your assets folder,  one of your textures is marked Render As:Template Image.  Texture atlases do not support this render mode, so you need to change it back to Default

Comment: Could this cause a memory leak because I have been having memory issues with that same atlas?

Comment: If you are getting a warning then I am assuming it is going to just ignore it in the code and go to default.  Doubt it will cause memory issues.